# Numerical Analysis - show something about the rate of convergence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, logarithms

We are given an iterative method for finding roots, $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$, we are given the rate of convergence of this method is $p$, and also that:

$$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{|e_{n+1}|}{|e_{n}|^p} = c$$

where $e_n = |x-x_n|$ (I'm assuming that $x$ is the value to which $x_k$ is converging)

**Show that** $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{log|e_{n+1}|}{log|e_n|} = p$$

Here's what I did:

$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{|e_{n+1}|}{|e_{n}|^p} = c$ implies $$log(\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{|e_{n+1}|}{|e_{n}|^p})=log(c)$$

I assumed that $log(\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{|e_{n+1}|}{|e_{n}|^p}) = \lim _{n \to \infty}log(\frac{|e_{n+1}|}{|e_{n}|^p})$ **is this true? if so why?**, but suppose it is.

then

$\lim _{n \to \infty}log(\frac{|e_{n+1}|}{|e_{n}|^p})=log(c)$ implies that

$$p=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{log|e_{n+1}|-log(c)}{log|e_n|}$$

And here I am stuck. Unless $log(c)=0$ then I did not solve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that for any $c>ε>0$ and $n\ge n_ε$ large enough

$$c-\varepsilon<\frac{|e_{n+1}|}{|e_n|^p}<c+ε$$

to get useful inequalities.

---

And use $\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(|e_n|)=-\infty$.

Comment: Is it correct to say that since $\lim_{n \to \infty} log|e_n|=-\infty$ then $log(c)$ is negligible?

Comment: You can split a convergent part off of the limit. The fraction of constant divided by diverging converges to zero.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thank you.